# Page flip effect same as FlipBoard app?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, flipboard

I want to make the pages flip effect same as FlipBoard app ([here](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/us/app/flipboard/id358801284?mt=8)).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697694/page-flip-effect-same-as-flipboard-app) is same post but I can't use this answer (the github link died!).

Below is some screen shoot:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Check out [AFKPageFlipper](https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper) on [GitHub](https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper)